# I'm trying write code for accessing the Google Sheets File->Download option

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-sheets-macros

I have a sheet that I'm just trying to do a File->Download->Comma-separated-values.

I've tried doing a Macro Record when I do this manually, but the Macro is basically empty (other than just selecting a Range).

Any suggestions on how to add this functionality with code?

Comment: Welcome to SO! Please add some code of what you did so far and any errors you've encountered

Comment: Regarding any suggestions... start by reading https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/sheets.

Comment: My code is as follows.  I get no errors, but I don't know how to do the File->Download functionality: